# Need to Retrieve column headers from database using Datatables JQuery Plugin

Tags: jquery, jsp, jquery-plugins

I have a requirement  i need to generate reports based on application.I am planning to use Jquery Datatables +Servlets for it.But i have a question .But using JQuery Datatables in jsp i need to give to the columns names (hardcoded in jsp page) is there is any way that i can get the column headers ,along with data from database based on application?
please help me out on this issue?

Comment: Should be more specific with your question(s). Can get table schema easily enough. What problems are you having once you retrieve column data?

Comment: Requirement i have is I Have A Drop Down (With list of Applications) and next drop down contains list of Reports corresponding to the application along with Start and Edate Columns. When i click submit Report should be genereated dynamically.I Want to display all reports for application in a single page.But if i use Datatables plugin i need to hard code the theader tag?

Comment: can dynamically create header row based on table schema if you want all columns, or create arrays for heading text and fields wanted